# Python Decimals format

Tags: python, decimal

What is a good way to format a python decimal like this way?

1.00 --> '1'
1.20 --> '1.2'
1.23 --> '1.23'
1.234 --> '1.23'
1.2345 --> '1.23'

Comment: If you're using Decimal and not float you might also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal. `{:g}` doesn't chop off insignificant zeros from decimals.

Comment: It's not clear whether OP actually meant the `decimal.Decimal` standard library class, or the built-in floating-point type. However, either way, a better version of the question exists.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If you have Python 2.6 or newer, use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
'{0:.3g}'.format(num)
```

For Python 2.5 or older:

```
'%.3g'%(num)
```

Explanation:

`{0}`tells `format` to print the first argument -- in this case, `num`.

Everything after the colon (:) specifies the `format_spec`.

`.3` sets the precision to 3.

`g` removes insignificant zeros. See 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#fprintf

For example:

```
tests=[(1.00, '1'),
       (1.2, '1.2'),
       (1.23, '1.23'),
       (1.234, '1.23'),
       (1.2345, '1.23')]

for num, answer in tests:
    result = '{0:.3g}'.format(num)
    if result != answer:
        print('Error: {0} --> {1} != {2}'.format(num, result, answer))
        exit()
    else:
        print('{0} --> {1}'.format(num,result))
```

yields

```
1.0 --> 1
1.2 --> 1.2
1.23 --> 1.23
1.234 --> 1.23
1.2345 --> 1.23
```

---

Using Python 3.6 or newer, you could use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#code-equivalence):

```
In [40]: num = 1.234; f'{num:.3g}'
Out[40]: '1.23'
```

Comment: It seems this causes Python 2.7 to go into the scientific notation for larger numbers:
>>> "{0:.3g}".format(100.20)
'100'
>>> "{0:.3g}".format(1001.20)
'1e+03'

Comment: So how to set no `Exponent notation`. As `{:,2f}.format(number)` dose, but also removes insignificant zeros

Comment: @unutbu - Any idea how to get '{0:.3g}' to work for Python fStrings?

Comment: @ScottSkiles: `num=1.2345; f'{num:.3g}'` returns `'1.23'`. See this explanation of [code equivalence](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id28).

Comment: Awesome! Worth an edit to this answer? I found this elsewhere on SO.

Comment: the number `100.2` is returning `100`

Comment: This solution only works if there is only 1 digit in the whole number part. i.e. f"{12.34:.3g}" will not work as expected.

Answer (score 32):

Only first part of Justin's answer is correct.
Using "%.3g" will not work for all cases as .3 is not the precision, but total number of digits. Try it for numbers like 1000.123 and it breaks.

So, I would use what Justin is suggesting:

```
>>> ('%.4f' % 12340.123456).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'12340.1235'
>>> ('%.4f' % -400).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'-400'
>>> ('%.4f' % 0).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'0'
>>> ('%.4f' % .1).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'0.1'
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a function that will do the trick:

```
def myformat(x):
    return ('%.2f' % x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

And here are your examples:

```
>>> myformat(1.00)
'1'
>>> myformat(1.20)
'1.2'
>>> myformat(1.23)
'1.23'
>>> myformat(1.234)
'1.23'
>>> myformat(1.2345)
'1.23'
```

**Edit:**

From looking at other people's answers and experimenting, I found that g does all of the stripping stuff for you. So,

```
'%.3g' % x
```

works splendidly too and is slightly different from what other people are suggesting (using '{0:.3}'.format() stuff). I guess take your pick.

Comment: Nice. Much cleaner than mine.

Comment: When you get something like 0.0000005 though I believe '%.3g'%x will begin to give you exponents?

Answer (score 11):

If using 3.6 or newer, just use [f-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```
print(f'{my_var:.1f}')
```

Comment: @hc_dev I thought pythonists will figure it out, isn't a bot for these kind of adjustments btw?

Answer (score 10):

You can use "f-strings" (f for "formatted string literals"), the short format style from Python `v3.6` on:

```
f'{1.234:.1f}'
Out: '1.2'
```

Or, as a test:

```
f'{1.234:.1f}' == '1.2'
Out: True
```

By the way, you can also use this with variables.

```
x = 1.234
f'{x:.1f} and {x:.2f} and {x}'
Out: '1.2 and 1.23 and 1.234'
```

If you need to use quotes in the text, embed the text with `f'''...'''` instead of `f'...'`.

Answer (score 6):

Just use Python's standard [string formatting methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> "{0:.2}".format(1.234232)
'1.2'
>>> "{0:.3}".format(1.234232)
'1.23'
```

If you are using a Python version under 2.6, use

```
>>> "%f" % 1.32423
'1.324230'
>>> "%.2f" % 1.32423
'1.32'
>>> "%d" % 1.32423
'1'
```

Comment: This is not a general solution and won't work for numbers with trailing zeros.