# Number formatting in python

Tags: python, formatting, number-formatting

How can I make this python code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
a=4
b=2
c=1.0
d=1.456
print '%fx³ + %fx² + %fx + %f = 0' %(a,b,c,d)
```

print like this:

```
4x³ + 2x² + 1x + 1.456 = 0
```

instead of like this (how it prints currently):

```
4.000000x³ + 2.000000x² + 1.0000000x + 1.456000 = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print '%gx³ + %gx² + %gx + %g = 0' %(a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this > [Python Decimals format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format)