# drop trailing zeros from decimal

Tags: python, decimal

I have a long list of Decimals and that I have to adjust by factors of 10, 100, 1000,..... 1000000 depending on certain conditions.  When I multiply them there is sometimes a useless trailing zero (though not always) that I want to get rid of.  For example...

```
from decimal import Decimal

# outputs 25.0,  PROBLEM!  I would like it to output 25
print Decimal('2.5') * 10

# outputs 2567.8000, PROBLEM!  I would like it to output 2567.8
print Decimal('2.5678') * 1000
```

Is there a function that tells the decimal object to drop these insignificant zeros?  The only way I can think of doing this is to convert to a string and replace them using regular expressions.

Should probably mention that I am using python 2.6.5

EDIT
senderle's fine answer made me realize that I occasionally get a number like 250.0 which when normalized produces 2.5E+2.  I guess in these cases I could try to sort them out and convert to a int

Comment: Those trailing zeros are preserved as they represent the maximal precision of the expressions resulting in the value (which is considered significant to the Decimal type).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's probably a better way of doing this, but you could use `.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` to achieve the result that you want.

Using your numbers as an example:

```
>>> s = str(Decimal('2.5') * 10)
>>> print s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in s else s
25
>>> s = str(Decimal('2.5678') * 1000)
>>> print s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in s else s
2567.8
```

And here's the fix for the problem that [@gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974555/gerrit) pointed out in the comments:

```
>>> s = str(Decimal('1500'))
>>> print s.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in s else s
1500
```

Comment: _"if you do convert them to a string"_ - the OP _has_ to convert to a string at some point, since he is outputting text!

Comment: This is true.  I do have to convert them to text to output them.  Senderle's answer works fine if I want to keep them as a decimal but this one works for my purposes.

Comment: This should contain a conditional `if '.' in s`, otherwise it will change `1500` into `15`.

Comment: or `re.sub('\.0+$', '', s)` which is more compact but supposedly slower

Comment: @Eric says "the OP has to convert to a string" — extremely pedantically speaking, that's not necessary (if string means characters in contiguous memory): if for instance one can come up with a function from uint n to the nth character, one can output the characters one by one without ever constructing the complete string. More generally, it is possible to output a textual representation of a thing without ever storing the whole of the textual representation in memory (e.g. a recursive json printer). One could also imagine C's printf as an incremental outputter of each element.

Comment: After looking at the "proper" answer, with way more votes, bellow this one, I think this is an excellent example of "Although practicality beats purity".

Comment: This doesn't work for Decimal('2.5E10'). It will return 2.5E1, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 130):

You can use the [`normalize`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) method to remove extra precision.

```
>>> print decimal.Decimal('5.500')
5.500
>>> print decimal.Decimal('5.500').normalize()
5.5
```

To avoid stripping zeros to the left of the decimal point, you could do this:

```
def normalize_fraction(d):
    normalized = d.normalize()
    sign, digits, exponent = normalized.as_tuple()
    if exponent > 0:
        return decimal.Decimal((sign, digits + (0,) * exponent, 0))
    else:
        return normalized
```

Or more compactly, using `quantize` as suggested by [user7116](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal/11227743#comment14749895_11227743):

```
def normalize_fraction(d):
    normalized = d.normalize()
    sign, digit, exponent = normalized.as_tuple()
    return normalized if exponent <= 0 else normalized.quantize(1)
```

You could also use `to_integral()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769210/577088) but I think using `as_tuple` this way is more self-documenting.

I tested these both against a few cases; please leave a comment if you find something that doesn't work.

```
>>> normalize_fraction(decimal.Decimal('55.5'))
Decimal('55.5')
>>> normalize_fraction(decimal.Decimal('55.500'))
Decimal('55.5')
>>> normalize_fraction(decimal.Decimal('55500'))
Decimal('55500')
>>> normalize_fraction(decimal.Decimal('555E2'))
Decimal('55500')
```

Comment: Oooo, that works.  But I noticed that on something like 250.0 that this will convert it to 2.5e+02, not 250.  I realize that I did not say this in my OP.  Is there a work around for this.

Comment: Your other option is: `Decimal('5.000').quantize(Decimal('1.'))`.

Comment: @user7116 `d.quantize(Decimal('1.'))` will drop all digits, not just trailing zeros. For example, `Decimal('5.050').quantize(Decimal('1.'))` returns a `Decimal('5')`.

Answer (score 54):

Answer from [the `Decimal` FAQ](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq) in the documentation:

```
>>> def remove_exponent(d):
...     return d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()

>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5.00'))
Decimal('5')

>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5.500'))
Decimal('5.5')

>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5E+3'))
Decimal('5000')
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, since it's straight out of the documentation.

Comment: Note that this will fail when the integral decimal is larger than the number of digits in the context's precision. For example, `remove_exponent(Decimal('5e28'))` will raise `decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context`, although the default context otherwise is perfectly capable of representing 5e28.

Answer (score 30):

Answer is mentioned in FAQ (https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq) but does not explain things.

To drop trailing zeros for fraction part you should use `normalize`:

```
>>> Decimal('100.2000').normalize()
Decimal('100.2')
>> Decimal('0.2000').normalize()
Decimal('0.2')
```

But this works different for numbers with leading zeros in sharp part:

```
>>> Decimal('100.0000').normalize()
Decimal('1E+2')
```

In this case we should use `to_integral':

```
>>> Decimal('100.000').to_integral()
Decimal('100')
```

So we could check if there's a fraction part:

```
>>> Decimal('100.2000') == Decimal('100.2000').to_integral()
False
>>> Decimal('100.0000') == Decimal('100.0000').to_integral()
True
```

And use appropriate method then:

```
def remove_exponent(num):
    return num.to_integral() if num == num.to_integral() else num.normalize()
```

Try it:

```
>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('100.2000'))
Decimal('100.2')
>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('100.0000'))
Decimal('100')
>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('0.2000'))
Decimal('0.2')
```

Now we're done.

Answer (score 8):

Use the format specifier `%g`. It seems remove to trailing zeros.

```
>>> "%g" % (Decimal('2.5') * 10)
'25'
>>> "%g" % (Decimal('2.5678') * 1000)
'2567.8'
```

It also works without the `Decimal` function

```
>>> "%g" % (2.5 * 10)
'25'
>>> "%g" % (2.5678 * 1000)
'2567.8'
```

Comment: `%g` only supports ints and floats so `Decimal` will be cast to float.

Mypy warns about the type error: `Incompatible types in string interpolation (expression has type "Decimal", placeholder has type "Union[int, float]")`.

"%g" % Decimal('200000000.123456789')  => '2e+06'

vs https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769210/3720597

str(remove_exponent(Decimal('2000000.123456789'))) => '2000000.123456789'

Answer (score 1):

#### I ended up doing this:

```py
import decimal

def dropzeros(number):
    mynum = decimal.Decimal(number).normalize()
    # e.g 22000 --> Decimal('2.2E+4')
    return mynum.__trunc__() if not mynum % 1 else float(mynum)

print dropzeros(22000.000)
22000
print dropzeros(2567.8000)
2567.8
```

note: casting the return value as a string will limit you to 12 significant digits

Comment: Converting to float loses precision. Also, your examples pass floats to `dropzeros`, not decimals.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, because it returns the number as float instead of string ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of [A-IV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769210/2234013)

**NOTE** that `Decimal('0.99999999999999999999999999995').normalize()` will round to `Decimal('1')`

```py
def trailing(s: str, char="0"):
    return len(s) - len(s.rstrip(char))

def decimal_to_str(value: decimal.Decimal):
    """Convert decimal to str

    * Uses exponential notation when there are more than 4 trailing zeros
    * Handles decimal.InvalidOperation
    """
    # to_integral_value() removes decimals
    if value == value.to_integral_value():
        try:
            value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(1))
        except decimal.InvalidOperation:
            pass
        uncast = str(value)
        # use exponential notation if there are more that 4 zeros
        return str(value.normalize()) if trailing(uncast) > 4 else uncast
    else:
        # normalize values with decimal places
        return str(value.normalize())
        # or str(value).rstrip('0') if rounding edgecases are a concern
```

Comment: The rounding to 1 will happen because of the contexts precision, setting e.g. decimal.getcontext().prec = 100 will cause it to not round there, at the expense of performance

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:g` to achieve this:

```py
'{:g}'.format(3.140)
```

gives

```py
'3.14'
```

Comment: This is the same response than @Friedrich, so the same error

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
'{:f}'.format(decimal.Decimal('2.5') * 10).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
```

Comment: Nope, Decimal('10') outputs as '1' using this approach.

Comment: Correct.  I'll leave my answer here so that the world can see why not to do this :)

Comment: This answer is equivalent to the accepted one, and the issue is equivalent to the 5-th comment to it. I see no reason why not to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different possibility, I used `to_tuple()` to achieve the same result.

```
def my_normalize(dec):
    """
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("12.500"))
    Decimal('12.5')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("-0.12500"))
    Decimal('-0.125')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("0.125"))
    Decimal('0.125')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("0.00125"))
    Decimal('0.00125')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("125.00"))
    Decimal('125')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("12500"))
    Decimal('12500')
    >>> my_normalize(Decimal("0.000"))
    Decimal('0')
    """
    if dec is None:
        return None

    sign, digs, exp = dec.as_tuple()
    for i in list(reversed(digs)):
        if exp >= 0 or i != 0:
            break
        exp += 1
        digs = digs[:-1]

    if not digs and exp < 0:
        exp = 0

    return Decimal((sign, digs, exp))
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use modules 10 from a multiple of 10 to check if there is remainder? No remainder means you can force int()

```
if (x * 10) % 10 == 0:
    x = int(x)
```

x = `2/1`
Output: `2`

x = `3/2`
Output: `1.5`