# Shortest identical decimal representation

Tags: python, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [drop trailing zeros from decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal)

How do I get the shortest representation of a `Decimal` that compares equal?

For example:

- `Decimal('89.00')` -> `'89'`
- `Decimal('123.010')` -> `'123.01'`
- `Decimal('0.0')` -> `'0'`

Currently, I have my own implementation which first converts to a string, with

```
if chanstr.endswith('0'):
    chanstr = chanstr[:chanstr.rfind('.')]
```

which works fine and is only 2 LOC; but is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Closed as duplicate because I discovered the other question only after writing this one, but this one is still a useful path for future people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [normalize](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) method to achieve this:

```
In [112]: print(decimal.Decimal("89.00").normalize())
89
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227743/974555).