# Format python decimal as [-.0-9]*, no trailing zeros, value-preserving

Tags: python, decimal, string-formatting, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I'm looking for a method which takes a decimal.Decimal object `x` and returns a string `s`, such that:

- `x == Decimal(s)`
- `re.match("^-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(.[0-9]*[1-9])?$", s) is not None`
- `s != '-0'`

In other words, the method doesn't change the value of the Decimal object; it returns a string representation which is never in scientific notation (e.g. `1e80`), and never has any trailing zeros.

I would assume there is a standard library function which lets me do that, but I haven't found any.  Do you know of any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [drop trailing zeros from decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal)

Comment: The dupee suggests two solutions, `x.normalize()` and `str(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`; they both fail. ###

`str(Decimal('1e-20')).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` is `'1e-2'`, and `Decimal('1e-2') != Decimal('1e-20')`, violating the equality condition.

###

`Decimal('10').normalize()` is `'1E+1'`, which violates the regex condition.

###

Using `'{:f}'.format(x)` seems to work, though.

Comment: But the question is exactly the same, even though the answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

`n.normalize()` truncates decimals with more than 28 digits of precision, but you can use string formatting and a manual check for negative zero:

```
'{:f}'.format(abs(n) if n.is_zero() else n)
```