# Remove trailing zeros after the decimal point in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, decimal-point

I am using Python 2.7. I need to replace `"0"` string at the end.

Say, a = "2.50":

```
 a = a.replace('0', '')
```

I get a = 2.5, and I am fine with this result.

Now a = "200":

```
 a = a.replace('0', '')
```

I get a = 2, and this output is as per design I agreed. But I expect the output a = 200.

Actually what I am looking is

> when any value after decimal point at the end is `"0"` replace that `"0"`
>   with None value.

Below are the examples and I am expecting results.

```
IN: a = "200"
Out: a = 200
In: a = "150"
Out: a = 150
In: a = 2.50
Out: a = 2.5
In: a = "1500"
Out: a = 1500
In: a = "1500.80"
Out: a = 1500.8
In: a = "1000.50"
Out: a = 1000.5
```

Not a value is string.

Note: sometimes `a = 100LL` or `a = 100.50mt`.

Comment: do you need to remove the "0" only for floats ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drop trailing zeros from decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal)

Comment: Yes. Note not at the end only at end i may get two strings

Comment: assuming the `a` type is `str` then you could use `s[-1]`, so that it only grab the last character in the string.

Comment: `a.rstrip('0') if '.' in a else a` ?

Comment: what is your expected output for input 2.0? Is it 2 or 2.0?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: the specifications have changed: there can be additional tailing text.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ughhh well i guess that happens when not all info is given from the start :/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a *regular expression*:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'(?:(\.)|(\.\d*?[1-9]\d*?))0+(?=\b|[^0-9])')

b = rgx.sub('\2',a)
```

Where `b` is the result of removing tailing zeros after the decimal point from `a`.

We can write this in a nice function:

```
import re

tail_dot_rgx = re.compile(r'(?:(\.)|(\.\d*?[1-9]\d*?))0+(?=\b|[^0-9])')

def remove_tail_dot_zeros(a):
    return tail_dot_rgx.sub(r'\2',a)
```

And now we can test this:

```
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.00')
'2'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('200')
'200'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('150')
'150'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.59')
'2.59'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.50')
'2.5'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.500')
'2.5'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.000')
'2'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('2.0001')
'2.0001'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('1500')
'1500'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('1500.80')
'1500.8'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('1000.50')
'1000.5'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('200.50mt')
'200.5mt'
>>> remove_tail_dot_zeros('200.00mt')
'200mt'
```

Comment: sorry I did not update in question now i Have updated. This will not work remove_tail_dot_zeros('200.50mt')

Comment: Sir, I got issue again i get a value like remove_tail_dot_zeros('200.00000mt') and I got output like 200.mt  any fix?

Comment: @kitty: you want one zero? Please next time add specifications for *corner cases* to your question.

Comment: No Zero required at end sir, with this remove_tail_dot_zeros('200.00000mt'). I get 200.mt this dot is not required. This earlier not noticed after testing I have noticed it.

Comment: So you want to remove the decimal dot?

Comment: Yes exactly sir

Comment: @kitty: updated. Can you please in future provide full specifications in your question. This question is hard to answer simply because information is *missing*.

Comment: Sure, Thanks and your points to be noted sir. Future i will provide full info

Answer (score 2):

Look for `'.'` in the item and them decide to remove the trailing (right-side) zero:

```
>>> nums = ['200', '150', '2.50', '1500', '1500.80', '100.50']
>>> for n in nums:
...     print n.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in n else n
... 
200
150
2.5
1500
1500.8
100.5
```

Comment: sorry I did not update in question now i Have updated.  it wont work when value is 250.50mt i need it as 250.5mt

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re

def strip(num):

    string = str(num)
    ext = ''

    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',string): 
        ext = str(num)[-2:]
        string = str(num).replace(ext, '')


    data = re.findall('\d+.\d+0$', string)
    if data:
        return data[0][:-1]+ext

    return string+ext
```

Comment: sorry I did not update in question now i Have updated. it wont work when value is 250.50mt i need it as 250.5mt

Comment: Please try this

Comment: Sir i may get many characters like ll mt kk bb those are not predictable