# How do I get rid of extra zeroes in django DecimalField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using a DecimalField in my model as I need quite a few decimal places for some of the values. But for some of the values I don't need as many zeroes. The problem is in the same field I will have some values that are 0.76 and other values that are 0.0001548337258. Unfortunately FloatField is not accurate enough for my needs.

But when I use:

```
 class Part(models.Model):
      dec_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=15)
```

I unfortunately get the same amount of empty 0's on my 0.76.

I would like the output when I call that field to be 0.76 in that location, and 0.00000037. Currently my output is:

```
 0.760000000000000
 0.000154833725800
```

I am trying to get my output to be:

```
 0.76
 0.0001548337258
```

Is there a way to remedy this?

---

**Edit**:

Normalize works to drop the decimals. But I am not sure where to implement that normalize method to the DecimalField in Django.

I tried to do it in the views.py file but got this error.

```
 AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'normalize'
```

Here is a minimal version of my views.py that I tried..

```
 def parts(request):
      part = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=part_pk)
      noZero = Part.dec_number
      noZero.normalize()
      return render(request, part.html, {'noZero':noZero})
```

I also tried:

```
 def parts(request):
      part = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=part_pk)
      noZero = Part.dec_number.normalize()
      return render(request, part.html, {'noZero':noZero})
```

---

I tried normalizing in models.py:

```
 class Part(models.Model):
     part_material_density = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=15)
     noZeroDen = dec_number.normalize()
```

But that gives me the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'DecimalField' object has no attribute 'normalize'
```

---

---

**What worked**:

In my views.py I changed the Part.dec_number.normalize() to part.dec_number.normalize()

```
def parts(request):
      part = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=part_pk)
      noZero = part.dec_number.normalize()
      return render(request, part.html, {'noZero':noZero})
```

---

**Something Else I Struggled with**:

I couldn't figure out how to get each item in the model to normalize before outputting to my HTML page.

I ended up looping through each part within my views.py and normalizing the field itself, instead of changing it's name. Hopefully this will not cause issues in the future, but I don't believe it will, and everything seems to be working as intended.

Here is the loop I used.

```
def parts(request):
    parts = Part.Objects.all()

    for part in parts:
        part.dec_number = part.dec_number.normalize()

    return render(request, 'parts.html', {'parts':parts})
```

Hopefully this can help someone else!

Comment: is this your answer? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227620/drop-trailing-zeros-from-decimal

Comment: While that is somewhat helpful. I am not able to implement that solution. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`normalize()`**--(PyDocs)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) method

```
part_instance.dec_number.normalize()
```

Comment: At what level do I normalize it? I tried to do it in the views.py file, but I get an error: AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'normalize'

Comment: at the object level. Can you add the error traceback and "minimal code of views.py" to the question?

Comment: Ok, I added the code. At the object level? Wouldn't that be in the views.py method?

Comment: Change the line, **`noZero = part.dec_number.normalize()`**