# Present a Decimal in the most readable format

Tags: python, decimal, string-formatting

So I'm trying to make a function that returns a stringified decimal in the most readable format. These are the requirements I have created for myself:

1. If the absolute exponent of the number is greater than or equal to 9, it should be presented using scientific notation (eg `25000000000 -> 2.5E+9`, `0.0000000036 -> 3.6E-9`)
2. Otherwise, the number should be presented as a standard notation decimal, with minimal trailing zeros (eg `103.400000 -> 103.4`, `0.000005600 -> 0.0000056`)

Currently, I'm using some code that I modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769210/6335363), but I can't really see a way to get it to match my requirements exactly.

Currently, my solution is as follows:

```py
def stringifyDecimal(d: Decimal):
    # If d is within a reasonable range for printing as a normal number
    a = abs(math.log10(abs(d)))
    if a < 9:
        r = d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()
    else:
        r = d.normalize()
    return str(r)
```

This works great for larger numbers:

- `stringifyDecimal(D('1E5')) -> '10000'`
- `stringifyDecimal(D('1E9')) -> '1E+9'`

But for very small fractions, it will always be returned in scientific notation:

- `stringifyDecimal(D('1E-7')) -> '1E-7'`

This is because of the `...else d.normalize()` part of the 5th line, which returns a Decimal that will stringify to scientific notation by default. Sadly, formatting options won't work for this as [they require me to know the exact precision that I want to format to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658777/6335363).

Is there a way that I can force the Decimal type to display a very small fraction as a decimal rather than in scientific notation?

Comment: You can do some print debugging after getting value of a. and check it `1E-7`

Comment: So, what's your lower limit?  Presumably you don't want `23E-23` displayed out fully.

Comment: @xcodz-dot I've already done this, and it works as intended.

Comment: @TimRoberts My lower limit is also 9. `1E-8` should print as a decimal, but `1E-9` should print in scientific notation.

Comment: then the problem is within the if block

Comment: the condition `d == d.to_integral()` is not True that is why it is normalizing it

Comment: The problem is specifically with stringifying Decimals @xcodz-dot. `str(Decimal("1E-7").normalize())` gives "1E-7", whereas I want it to display as "0.0000001"

Comment: I'm aware that `d == d.to_integral()` isn't `True`. This is because it's checking for whole numbers, which is where the problem is - I need a system that presents numbers as decimals rather than scientific notation regardless of whether something is a whole number or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the most effective method I've found is to use string formatting.

```py
d = Decimal('152')
print(f"{d:f}") # Format as a standard decimal
print(f"{d:e}") # Format in scientific notation
```

from this, my solution is as follows:

```py
def strDecimal_Sci(d: Decimal) -> str:
    return f"{d.normalize():e}"

def strDecimal_Norm(d: Decimal) -> str:
    return f"{d.normalize():f}"

def stringifyDecimal(d: Decimal) -> str:
    if d == 0: return "0"
    a = abs(math.log10(abs(d)))
    if a < 9:
        return strDecimal_Norm(d)
    else:
        return strDecimal_Sci(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way, your code fails for 0 because of the log.  See what you think about this.  For values between 10-7 and 10-9, I multiply by 100, convert to string, then insert the two zeros:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def stringifyDecimal(d: Decimal):
    # If d is within a reasonable range for printing as a normal number
    if not d:
        return "0"
    a = math.log10(abs(d))
    if 0 < a < 9:
        r = d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()
        r = str(r)
    elif -8 < a < -6:
        r = str((d*100).normalize())
        r = r[:2] + '00' + r[2:]
    else:
        r = d.normalize()
        r = str(r)
    return r

tests = [
    "12e12", "11e11", "10e10", "9e9", "8e8", "7e7", "6e6", "5e5", "4e4", "3e3", "2e2", "1e1",
    "0",
    "1e-1", "2e-2", "3e-3", "4e-4", "5e-5", "6e-6", "7e-7", "8e-8", "9e-9", "10e-10"
]

for test in tests:
    print(stringifyDecimal(Decimal(test)))
```

Output:

```
1.2E+13
1.1E+12
1E+11
9E+9
800000000
70000000
6000000
500000
40000
3000
200
10
0
0.1
0.02
0.003
0.0004
0.00005
0.000006
0.0000007
0.00000008
9E-9
1E-9
```

Comment: This looks pretty great actually! One small fix might be to replace `elif -8 < a < -6:` with `elif -8 <= a < -6:`, as otherwise it won't work correctly for the input `1E-8`. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Thankfully, I didn't need to worry about the leading zero as that is dealt with earlier in the program (when it tries to present as a fraction first)