# How to prevent Python from removing the leading zeroes in "0005"

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to create a list of numbers from 00000 to 99999, and I want to save it in a file. But the problem is that Python removes the leading zeroes, making 00000 just 0. Here's my code.

```
f=open("numbers","w")
x=00000
y=99999
while y>=x:
    zzz=str(x)+'\n'
    f.write(zzz)
    x=x+1
```

I want to save these numbers like this:

00000
00001
00002
And so on...

I am new to Python and I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Comment: Leading zeros are insignificant to a *number*: `0` = `000` = `00000` even though they have different *textual* representations. Check the duplicate question(s). (Sometimes a leading zero indicates octal, but that is tangental.)

Answer (score 4):

Just use [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> print('{:05}'.format(1))
00001
```

Answer (score 3):

The third possibility is [`zfill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
str(x).zfill(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `'%05d' % x` instead of `str(x)`.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

x=000 and x=0 are stored exactly the same way...as the integer zero.  What you want is to print strings formatted the way you require.  Here's what you are looking for:

Here's what you are looking for:

```
with open('numbers','w') as f:          # open a file (automatically closes)
    for x in range(10000):              # x = 0 to 9999
        f.write('{:05}\n'.format(x))    # write as a string field formatted as width 5 and leading zeros, and a newline character.
```