# Formatting to two decimal places in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Fairly new to coding and having some confusion with my homework. I want to have the printed results only go to two decimal places and not any farther. I have been messing around with some format options and trying to find the answer online but couldn't understand what I needed to do, any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
 #Ingredients per 48 cookies
    sugar = 1.5
    butter = 1
    flour = 2.75

    #what percent of 48 are the ingredients
    sugar1 = (1.5/48)

    butter1 = (1/48)

    flour1 = (2.75/48)

    #ask for amount of cookies from user
    cookies = int (input('How many cookies would you like to bake? '))


    #calculate ingredient amounts
    sugar2 = (sugar1 * cookies)
    format(sugar2, '.2f')

    butter2 = (butter1 * cookies)
    format(butter2, '.2f')

    flour2 = (flour1 * cookies)
    format(flour2, '.2f')

    print ('To make', cookies, ' you need', sugar2, 'cups of sugar,',
           butter2, 'cups of butter, and', flour2, ' cups of flour.')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Decimals format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
print('%.2f' % sugar2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output 2 digits:

```
for n in [1.23,1.234,1.1,1.7846]:
    print('{:.2f}'.format(n))
```

Output:

```
1.23
1.23
1.10
1.78
```

Have a quick read here for python 3 formattings:  https://pyformat.info/#number or here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 0):

`format` is not a declaration, or something that alters its argument: it *produces* a string that you need to include in your output.