# python decimal context output

Tags: python, decimal

I want to output certain decimal variables with certain formatting, and my understanding is you do this with contexts from the decimal class. How would I go about doing this?

```
 x = decimal.Decimal(2000.0)
```

And now I want to print this in the format `$2,000.00` 
How would I go about doing that with a context?

Comment: check this link     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Comment: You *do not* need the context output, also they cannot deal with comma separators. Formatted output is sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: This is what I am wanting to do per this recipe:                                                      https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#recipes               the moneyfmt function that they show.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = 2000
print("${:.2f}".format(float(val)))   # This outputs $2000.00 (no comma)
```

But to add to comma you simply add it between the colon and decimal like so:

```
print("${:,.2f}".format(float(val)))   # This outputs $2,000.00 (with comma)
money = 65434562338.89
print("${:,.2f}".format(float(money))) # Outputs: $65,434,562,338.89
```

The `:.2f` formats the output so that only 2 decimal places are displayed where `:.3f` will show 3 decimals like `$2000.000` and so forth.

Comment: Ive added it to my solution

Comment: So this snippet is from the python documentation in the decimal module:

Comment: This was quickly done within the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> "${:,.2f}".format(decimal.Decimal(2000))
'$2,000.00'

>>> "${:,.2f}".format(decimal.Decimal("2000.987"))
'$2,000.99'

>>> "${:,.2f}".format(decimal.Decimal("1000000.1"))
'$1,000,000.10'

>>> "${:,.2f}".format(decimal.Decimal("123456789123456789123456789.12345"))
'$123,456,789,123,456,789,123,456,789.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `locale` module

Example code:

```
import locale

x = 2000.00
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
locale.currency( x )
locale.currency( x, grouping=True )
```

Output:

```
'$2,000.00'
```

Reference: [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Comment: Changing the `locale` causes a global change in behaviour for all threads in a program simply to satisfy printing a number.