# Force python to print a certain number of decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program which takes some floating type values and writes to a file.

I round these numbers to 6 decimal places and then convert to a string type before writing to file.

```
file.write(str(round(value,6)))
```

However with certain numbers the value written to file is in the format shown below.

```
e.g. 3e-06 or 4e-03
```

How can I avoid this and instead write out in decimal format like

```
0.000003 and 0.004000
```

How can I print exactly 6 figures after the decimal point.

Comment: Perhaps this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Comment: @Sanketh Not exactly - `g` works differently from `f`. I included it in my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the *f-string* `f'{value:.6f}'`.

Example:

```
value = 0.234
print(f'{value:.6f}')

value = 1
print(f'{value:.6f}')

value = 0.95269175
print(f'{value:.6f}')
```

Output:

```
0.234000
1.000000
0.952692
```

Also, in the answer linked in a comment, there was reference to `:g`. That *can* work, but probably not in this situation, because `g` *may* print scientific notation where appropriate, *and* discards insignificant zeroes. Consider a slightly modified example using `g`:

```
value = 0.234
print(f'{value:.6g}')

value = 1
print(f'{value:.6g}')

value = 0.000000000095269175
print(f'{value:.6g}')
```

Output:

```
0.234
1
9.52692e-11
```

Comment: try  `` print(format(14.4499923, '.3f')) ``

Comment: @junior_software What are you trying to say?

Comment: that you will need to do value = format(value, '.6f') and now value has 6 decimal points after the dot notice that it will print exactly 6 dots after the point and if you don't have it will pads your number with 0

Comment: @junior_software As it should be...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use basic string formatting:

```
a = 3e-06

# Outputs 0.000003
print('%.6f' % a)

# Outputs 0.000003000000
print('%.12f' % a)
```