# Print exact min value of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max, min

I am trying to print the exact minimum value from a list using the sample code below:

```
mylist = [value]

while True:
    price_list.append(value)
    low_value = min(value)
    print("min value = " float(low_value))


    time.sleep(600)
```

value is being constantly updated from my website scraper pulling data from my website. Often the actual value displayed is 19.9900, however, the output is "min value = 19.9" or "min value = 19" depending on the price change.

I would like the full value to be displayed (eg. 19.9900) and I am having trouble doing this.

Comment: Try not wrapping it around `float`

Comment: I did, it doesn't work. It prints "min value = 19"

Comment: Then it's the problem with your scraper function. Please add the code for that.

Comment: You were right, I have two parts to it! Thanks Jaiswal!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force python to print a certain number of decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217081/force-python-to-print-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
print(f"{low_value:.6f}")
```

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56217119/12648789) answer too for more details.

Comment: I tried this too. It didn't do the trick.

Comment: Thats because this code will cause a syntax error. @Brendan Try using `print(f"{low_value:.6f}")` instead.

Comment: Thanks @PacketLoss I missed out on the colon. Included it now:)