# How can this be solved in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Print air_temperature with 1 decimal point followed by C.

Sample output with input: 36.4158102
36.4C

This is my answer:
print('{x:.1f}'C.format(x=air_temperature))

Comment: You just need to move `C` inside the quotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help in the future, you need to provide a [mre] including any errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217081/force-python-to-print-a-certain-number-of-decimal-places) for more on formatting numbers, especially if you're using a version of Python 3 with f-strings (3.6+).

```
temp = 36.4158102

print('{x:.1f} C'.format(x=temp))

# or

print(f'{temp:.1f} C')  # 3.6+
```