# I cannot get decimals value of height in cm,it gives only round output

Tags: python

i want to get answer like if i input value for height 1 feet,it should give 30.48 cm as output,i want only 2 values after decimal

```
while True:
            try:
                height  = float(input('\nEnter your height in feet:'))
            except ValueError:
                print("\nPlease enter only number")
            else:
                break
cm = (height*30.48)
print("\nYour height is  %d cm." % cm)
```

Comment: This would explain on how to proceed with formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Comment: You are using `%d` so it shows an integer. Use `%.2f` if you want to shows two decimals. Note that it will also show `x.00` if x is already a round number.

Comment: Also, consider taking a look at https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this; but as far as I know using the `.format`-method with your string is the recommended way in Python 3.
It allows you to cut off the value or to round the value in a correct way (for example, as asked, with 2 decimals):

```py
while True:
            try:
                height  = float(input('\nEnter your height in feet:'))
            except ValueError:
                print("\nPlease enter only number")
            else:
                break
cm = (height*30.48)
print("\nYour height is {} cm.".format(round(cm,2)))
```

You could also round the result itself before:

```py
cm = round(height*30.48, 2)
print("\nYour height is {} cm.".format(cm))
```

or use the decimal definition in the brackets as follows:

```py
cm = (height*30.48)
print("\nYour height is {:.2f} cm.".format(cm))
```