# How to round off a floating number to one decimal place from the print line python function directly

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have the following code

```
for x in range(10):
  
    print(f'Machine Busy Val     : {read_log ("Machine_busy_value")}')
```

read_log is the function and it is getting the machine_busy_value. it is currently returning a floating number but I would like it to return the value in 2 decimal places. How can I go about that? Any type of suggestion would be appreciated. I am using python 2.7 if that helps

Comment: If you’re using Py2.7 (or anything <3.6) the `f-string` notation will fail in a syntax error.  Are you sure you’re on 2.7?

Comment: Yeah, i am on python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using format()

```
print ("{val:.1f}".format(val=read_log("Machine_busy_value") ))
```

That's python 2.7 (which doesn't have f-strings). There are plenty of [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format) already out there

If you're on python 3.7, then you can just end your read_log call in the string with the `:.2f` to format it.

```
f'Machine Busy Val     : {read_log ("Machine_busy_value"):.1f}'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The python 3.7 implementation worked. This is strange because when I type py --version on my terminal I see python 3.7.0. Not sure what is that about. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Python has a round function which you can call as such:
round(The number you want to round, The number of decimal points)

So you should save your floating number, round it then print it.

Comment: That was my initial plan but i was wondering is there no way to do it directly within that line of code itself?

Comment: Yes, look into **string formatting**.  A little research on your own will uncover the answer.

Comment: You could do: f"Machine Busy Val : {round(read_log ("Machine_busy_value"), 2)}